Why is the expected payout equal to the $p_1$?
The following problem is from Mark Joshi's book:

I pick a number n from 1 to 100. If you guess correctly, I pay you $n and zero otherwise. How much would you pay to play this game?

He says that the probability to pick $k$ is $p_k= \frac{1}{k}(\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i})^{-1}$.
This has been discussed already extensively in the post.
What I want to know is that the expected payout then should be:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\text{payout}] &= \sum_{j=1}^{100} j \cdot p_j \\
&=  \sum_{j=1}^{100} j \cdot \frac{1}{j}(\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i})^{-1} \\
&=  \sum_{j=1}^{100} (\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i})^{-1} \\
&= 100 \cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i})^{-1}
\end{align}
Why is the answer $(\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i})^{-1}$?

It’s generally not a good idea to use the same index in two different sums.

Totally missed it. Thanks!

The rules are not clear.  Do you pick $n$ strategically or do you choose it uniformly at random or something else?

You calculated as if the guesser always guesses right.
Since the optimal strategy for the picker makes the guesser indifferent among strategies, we can calculate the payout by assuming that the guesser has a deterministic strategy. Then exactly one of the $100$ terms in your sum is actually paid out.
